# capturing packets from a specific client UDP (Python)

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I have a question regarding sniffing packets from a specific client. I am running a very simple UDP server as follows:

```
from socket import *

IPv4 = ""
Port = 54345

ServerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
ServerSock.bind((IPv4, Port))
print "Socket is ready to receive data.."

while True:
    data, addr = ServerSock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print data
```

and I intend to capture every packet that comes to the port number(54345) and parse its header values. I think it is doable if the packets are saved to .pcap file and probably use scapy to process them but is it possible to process every packet once it arrives using "socket.recvfrom"?. Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What you're doing here should work fine. Assuming nothing else is bound to `('', 54345)`, it will receive every datagram sent to that port and print it to `stdout`, so you can redirect the script's output to a file and process with `scapy` or whatever you want. So… what is this not doing that you want it to do?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. the output of the recvfrom is in the form of ('data', ('add', 54345)). can that be saved as a full packet in a .pcap file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got the data. However, what you've got is UDP packets and source addresses; if you want the complete raw packet, with the IPv4 and UDP headers, that's different.

On some platforms, you can set a normal UDP socket to `IP_HDRINCL`, or there are other equivalents. If you do this, each `recvfrom` will include the headers in the data, so you've already got everything you want.

On other platforms, you can use `SOCK_RAW` instead of `SOCK_DGRAM`. What you can do with raw sockets varies dramatically. On many Unix platforms, you can use `IPPROTO_UDP` with `SOCK_RAW`, and then `bind` to a normal UDP address and port, although there may be restrictions, and they're different on each platform. For example, on OS X, you have to be root to create a raw socket, and you can only bind a raw socket to a single-interface address (meaning no `''`/`INADDR_ANY`/`'0.0.0.0'`). If you Google for "SOCK_RAW Python" and "SOCK_RAW " you should be able to find out what you need. (The last example in the [sockets module docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) shows how to use raw sockets on Windows.)

Once you've got the data, saving it to a `pcap` file isn't hard. The format is documented at [LibpcapFileFormat](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat) at The Wireshark Wiki. If you have any familiarity with the stdlib `struct` module, it should be easy to figure out how to write this format. Here's a brief sample:

```
pcap_hdr = struct.pack('=IHHiIII',
                       0xa1b2c3d4, # magic number
                       2, 4,       # pcap 2.4 format
                       0,          # UTC timezone for timestamps
                       0,          # "in practice, all tools set it to 0"
                       65535,      # max packet length
                       228)        # LINKTYPE_IPV4, or maybe you want LINKTYPE_RAW
pcapfile.write(pcap_hdr)
```

If you don't want to do that yourself, I don't have any experience with using libraries to write pcap files, but `scapy` would be the first place I'd look, then the [`python-libpcap`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pylibpcap/) bindings for [`libpcap`](http://www.tcpdump.org/)/[`WinPcap`](http://www.winpcap.org/). If none of those work, check around PyPI.

If all of this sounds beyond you, you probably don't want to do things this way. Just run your UDP server, and use Wireshark to capture all of the packets sent to it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. i have come across 'SOCK_RAW' and it seemed to me that it worked like a sniffer to all incoming packets. all what you mentioned makes sense but i was wondering if i could capture and save packet from specific client port number.

Comment: If you're trying to capture all packets from a specific client port (whether to a specific local port or not), that's a different question. The details are highly platform-specific, but `python-libpcap` (linked above) provides some very nice abstractions that will make it easier, and IIRC one of the examples is very nearly what you want (it sniffs everything on eth0/en0/etc., and filters on TCP dst port 80; adapting to filter on UDP src port 54345 should be easy).

Comment: Thanks .. I shall give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. That's what your program already does actually.

Comment: maybe my question is not that clear, if it does it.. how can i get for instance the IP identification number from each received packet? thanks