# How to detect or capture UDP packet on a local port(69) with Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, sockets, networking

I have tried this:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
s.bind(('', 69))
while True
    try :
        databuffer, (raddress, rport) = s.recvfrom(1024)
    except socket.timeout:
        logging.error("Write timeout on socket")
        continue
```

But the result says nothing was received(no package!) in databuffer. But I used Wireshark that really captured the packets!
I have found some solutions: [How Do I Use Raw Socket in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117958/how-do-i-use-raw-socket-in-python)
   The last example shows how to write a very simple network sniffer with raw sockets on Windows. The example requires administrator privileges to modify the interface:

```
import socket
# the public network interface
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

# create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.bind((HOST, 0))

# Include IP headers
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

# receive all packages
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

# receive a package
print s.recvfrom(65565)

# disabled promiscuous mode
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF) "
```

Mine:

```
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
s.bind((HOST, 69))
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
```

It works! But there is another problem: the local port 69!

```
s.bind((HOST, 69))
```

Packets captured are all from port 0 but not 69!

I was wondering if there are even better ways to do that.

On os:windows server 2003 R2 standard edition sp2 -32bits 
python 2.7.1

Comment: `s.bind((HOST, 0))` means only that the port will be chosen on random from 1024-65535 range. Try setting your port value from 69 to one from that range.

Comment: so when s.bind((HOST, 69)) means ?! or i just detect 69 it means  range(69,69)!

Comment: the key point of my question like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203914/capturing-packets-from-a-specific-client-udp-python   " capture  packet from specific client port number" on windows platform SOCK_DGRAM doesnt work ,so i have to use SOCK_RAW instead of SOCK_DGRAM.